# Retrieving data from Cloud Firestore with AsynkTaskLoader in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm new to Android and Firebase and I'm having this weird bug I don't understand. I have a RecyclerView that should display a list of Strings that have dates followed by a number. Now, I want to retrieve the data from Cloud Firestore and display it. For this purpose, I use an AsyncTaskLoader and in `loadInBackground()` I retrieve the data from Cloud Firestore. Now, when I start the activity, it shows the error message (and it will keep behaving this way no matter how many times I Hit the refresh button). However, if I turn off the screen and then turn it on, it shows the data the way I wish. The following is my code

```
public class MeasureListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    MeasuresAdapter.MeasuresAdapterOnClickHandler,
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String[]> {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private MeasuresAdapter mMeasuresAdapter;

private TextView mErrorMessageDisplay;

private ProgressBar mLoadingIndicator;

private static final int MEASURES_LOADER_ID = 0;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    /* Use AppCompatActivity's method getMenuInflater to get a handle on the menu inflater */
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    /* Use the inflater's inflate method to inflate our menu layout to this menu */
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.measures_list, menu);
    /* Return true so that the menu is displayed in the Toolbar */
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        invalidateData();
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(MEASURES_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_measure_list);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_measures);

    mErrorMessageDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_error_message_display);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mMeasuresAdapter = new MeasuresAdapter(this);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMeasuresAdapter);

    mLoadingIndicator = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_loading_indicator);

    int loaderId = MEASURES_LOADER_ID;

    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String[]> callback = MeasureListActivity.this;

    Bundle bundleForLoader = null;

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(loaderId, bundleForLoader, callback);
}

@Override
public Loader<String[]> onCreateLoader(int id, final Bundle loaderArgs) {



    return new AsyncTaskLoader<String[]>(this) {

        String[] mWMeasuresData = null;

        @Override
        protected void onStartLoading() {
            if (mWMeasuresData != null) {
                deliverResult(mWMeasuresData);
            } else {
                mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                forceLoad();
            }
        }


        private String[] aux;
        @Override
        public String[] loadInBackground() {


            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

            db.collection("medidas").whereEqualTo("id_user", "3Aq3g0czkarT8GIbyESV").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        QuerySnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
                        int tam = snapshot.getDocuments().size();
                        aux = new String[tam];
                        for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
                            String temp = "";
                            DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.getDocuments().get(i);
                            temp += doc.get("fecha") + " ";
                            temp += doc.get("valor");
                            aux[i] = temp;
                        }

                    }
                }
            });

            return aux;
        }


        public void deliverResult(String[] data) {
            mWMeasuresData = data;
            super.deliverResult(data);
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String[]> loader, String[] data) {
    mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mMeasuresAdapter.setMeasuresData(data);
    if (null == data) {
        showErrorMessage();
    } else {
        showMeasuresDataView();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<String[]> loader) {

}


private void invalidateData() {
    mMeasuresAdapter.setMeasuresData(null);
}


private void showMeasuresDataView() {
    /* First, make sure the error is invisible */
    mErrorMessageDisplay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    /* Then, make sure the weather data is visible */
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void showErrorMessage() {
    /* First, hide the currently visible data */
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    /* Then, show the error */
    mErrorMessageDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
@Override
public void onClick(String measure) {
    Context context = this;
    Class destinationClass = DetailMeasureActivity.class;
    Intent intentToStartDetailActivity = new Intent(context, destinationClass);
    intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, measure);
    startActivity(intentToStartDetailActivity);
}
```

}

Can you help me with this?...thanks in advance

Comment: You don't really need to use AsyncTaskLoader with Firestore.  Firestore APIs are already asynchronous, and it's no problem to repeat a fetch, because it will fetch from cache first.  Using a loader just adds a lot more code for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that when you call this block of code:

```
 mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            forceLoad();
```

You should also hide the error message view.

Also, on a more serious note, you do not need AsyncTaskLoader to get your data from firestore, firebase firestore already handles background work for you.

To be able to understand fully where the problem is from, you need to understand you activity lifecycle and add logs to mark critical events that will help you to know which block of code is called at any point in time. So I will encourage you to add logs for when the data loading starts, finishes and when you are hiding a view or showing a view just to be sure that all methods are called and also add logs to your activity lifecycles.